# IOS: Embedding views in stack creating a stack with > 10,000 pts size

Tags: ios

I am trying to embed 4 UILabels and a UIView into a stack view. I selected all the labels then click the 'embed in stack' option. This then causes the labels to disappear from the view controller with ridiculous widths and X positions (e.g. one of the labels went from a width of 300 pts to 61,000,000 pts.) All the views I am trying to embed have correct constraints with each other and the rest of the view controller.

I've attached a photo of the views I am trying to embed in a stack (giving them background colours for visibility).

[UI elements I want to embed in stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtUFg.png)

Answer (score 0):

> All the views I am trying to embed have correct constraints with each other

There's your problem (at least in part). Do you understand what a stack view *is*? It is nothing but a shortcut for making constrains on its embedded views. It is a *contraint maker*.

For a stack view to work on your labels, therefore, your labels must have *no* constraints to one another. Rather it is the stack view itself that must be constrained (and the failure to do that sounds like the other half of your problem).

Comment: Thanks for answering. When I embed the views with no constraints the same issue happens. The width and height of the stack view also become uneditable with respective values of 40 and 30 million.

Comment: Not if you fully constrain the stack view itself, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If u have a space when u want to put stackView, first put stackView, add constrains to that stackView and add the subviews on it.